# How can I share a file with iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have my app create a file, in this case it's actually an animated .gif.  This animated .gif is saved on the device and is all ready to go - what I want to do now is share this file when the user clicks the "Share" button.

Simply put, how can I achieve this?

Is there a way to just tell iOS to open up the share window and that I'm sharing an image?  Right now I can't find a way to do that, so instead I'm creating a new **UIImage** with a path to this animated .gif on the device, but this ends up converting my animated file into a static image.

**Again - I already have the animated .gif file created and saved on the user's device**.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit: To clarify, I'm used to Android, I just call up an intent to share a file and up pops a list of Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, etc, etc...  I basically want the equivalent of that, if possible.**

Comment: `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Comment: Share it with what?  A file requires an application for it to run.  Name one.

Comment: See I'm used to Android, I just call up an intent to share a file and up pops a list of Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, etc, etc...  I basically want the equivalent of that, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the UIActivityViewController document. This will open a sheet with all the ways available to share on the device. See here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011976-CH1-SW2 . You may want to initialize the ActivityViewController with images or UIActivityItemSource

Comment: See, thanks for that answer, but it doesn't help me.  I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but while that is what I want (in order to share), what I'm asking is how can I share an animated .gif specifically?  In Android all I have to do is specify the path to the file, say "this is an image", and call a share intent.  It seems in iOS you can share text, a URL, or a UIImage aka a static image, at least that's all I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and twitter not support UIActivityViewController, still in this used only limited application. Now this code very usedfully.

-(void)uploadImageToTwitter {

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                              ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                              completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     if (granted == YES)
     {
         NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account
                                     accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

         if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
         {
             ACAccount *twitterAccount =
             [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];
```

//
//                 NSURL *furl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
//                 NSURL *fileURL = [furl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"animation.gif"];

```
               NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_GIFURL];

              NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json"];

             SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest
                                       requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                       requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                       URL:requestURL parameters:nil];

             postRequest.account = twitterAccount;

             [postRequest addMultipartData:imageData
                                  withName:@"media"
                                      type:@"image/gif"
                                  filename:@"test.gif"];

             [postRequest
              performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                          NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
              {


                  NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];

                  NSString *mediaID = [json objectForKey:@"media_id_string"];


                  if (mediaID!=nil) {


                      NSURL *requestURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
                      NSDictionary *message2 = @{@"status": @"Here is the image",
                                                 @"media_ids": mediaID };

                      SLRequest *postRequest2 = [SLRequest
                                                 requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                 requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                 URL:requestURL2 parameters:message2];
                      postRequest2.account = twitterAccount;

                      [postRequest2
                       performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                                   NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                       {
                           // DONE!!!

                           UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notification" message:@"Upload Twitter Account" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                           [alert show];


                       }];

                  }

              }];
         }
     }
 }];
```

}